# SignalR Exception: The connection has not been established

Tags: asp.net, webforms, signalr

I am getting an exception that "The connection has not been established" when I try to invoke my hub class method using IHubProxy and I am unable figure out the issue. The connection has been made successful but the following line of code throw an error.

```
hubProxy.Invoke("SendNotificationToUser", new object[] { touser, message }).ContinueWith(task =>
                {
                    if (task.IsFaulted && task.Exception != null)
                    {
                        // log error
                    }
                });
```

here's my complete code..

```
[WebMethod]
        public static void NotfTest(string message)
        {
            var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:3052/CollegeBuilder/");
            IHubProxy hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("NotificationHub");
            var touser = "128";
            try
            {
                lock (hubConnection)
                {
                    if (hubConnection.State == Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.ConnectionState.Disconnected)
                    {
                        hubConnection.Start().Wait(2000);
                    }
                }

                hubProxy.Invoke("SendNotificationToUser", new object[] { touser, message }).ContinueWith(task =>
                {
                    if (task.IsFaulted && task.Exception != null)
                    {
                        // log error
                    }
                }); ;
            }
            finally
            {
                hubConnection.Stop();
            }
        }
```

Comment: This looks very different that they way I've set up SignalR so please forgive me if I ask some basic questions.  Is SendNotificationToUser supposed to send a notification from the hub to the client? (client meaning the client system)  What is user '128' is that a user Id or a connection or session Id?

Comment: The '128' is a user id just for the sake of testing I hard coded it.Yes you are right SendNotificationToUser is a method Used to send  a Notification to Client Via Hub.This method takes two parameters SendNotificationToUser(string touser, string message).

Comment: I don't think you're really getting an instance of the Hub.  I think you need to do something like: var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();  Then: context.Clients.Client(id).SendNotificationToUser()

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug your situation you should enable detailed errors.  See here for more information: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#handleerrors